# How to create ARFF dataSet for Multi-Labels text classification

Tags: text, weka, arff, multilabel-classification

Good afternoon,

Well, i want to perform a Multi-label text Classification, so, i choose MEKA (extension of Weka) to perform this task. However, i need to transform the document to a Vector of words, i use the GUI Weka but as you know it perform just a biary classification, for that i tend to use MEKA to perform this task,
the problem is how i create an arff file with multi labels
here is an example:
this is the text

> The addition of FMNH(2), to Vibrio harveyi luciferase at 2A°C in the presence of tetradecanal results in the formation of a highly fluorescent transient species with a spectral distribution indistinguishable from that of the bioluminescence. The bioluminescence reaches maximum intensity in 1.5 s and decays in a complex manner with exponential components of 10(-1) s(-1) , 7 x 10(-3)S(-1). and 7 x10(4)s(-1).

the labels are:

> "FM", "Fl", "Ki", "Luc", "Lum", "Time Factors"

the result i want to get:

> @attribute L-class {Luc, Lum, Limb,...}
>
> @attribute F-class {FM, Fl, Foot,...}
>
> @attribute o-class{Ki, TimeFactors, Adult, Aged, ...}
>
> @attribute All_words frequency
>
> @data
>
> FM,Fl,Ki,Luc,Lum,TimeFactors,2,4,6,8,8,7,4,0,1,2,2....

The acronyms are the labels, and the numbers are the Frequency of each term occuring in the text.
Someone could help me, i will be really thankful.

Comment: Did you figure out the solution? I am trying to do the same thing but running into some issues.